# Can't get boolean modifier to work?

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to use the boolean modifier to "etch" the logo into a block, but it is giving the error "Cannot execute boolean operation".

The file can be found here http://www.pasteall.org/blend/43089

I would greatly appreciate any assistance as I'm practically brand new to blender.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select logo go to edit mode press <kbd>W</kbd> and *Remove doubles*.

Then set the *Boolean* modifier to *Difference*.

[image: Render]

Comment: You're seriously the best, thank you! Would you be able to explain what causes the problem?

Comment: I really don't know. There was around 2k overlaping vertices and I think it was too much (?). Blender manual doesn't cover this situation: https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html

From my experience if you have got some problem check geometry first (normals, doubles).

Comment: @Connor Boolean modifiers only work with closed, watertight, *Manifold* meshes,**without** overlapping geometry, duplicate vertex or coinciding faces. If this answer helped you please consider marking it as correct or at least up voting it

Comment: I will of course mark it. Stack Exchange forces you to wait to mark an answer as correct. You were too fast!